# problem with prepare statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wrote this query but it has a error.

```
 String x = String.valueOf(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2) );


    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("select sportman_code, "
                + "customer_code from sportman where sportman_code = ?");

        preparedStatement1.setString(1, x);
        preparedStatement1.executeUpdate(); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
```

this is it's error

```
Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs
```

what is problem?

Comment: For all readers, the OP has edited the question and removed the line `resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();` which may make some answers confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 ResultSet resultSet =  preparedStatement1.executeQuery();
```

instead of

```
preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

For issuing SQL SELECT's you have to use [executeQuery](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) and not executeUpdate. Also i see a `;` hanging out there.